# How can remove the space between lines?

Tags: libreoffice

My libreoffice version is Libreoffice Community 7.4.7.2.

[image]

When i move cursor at the `'volume']` and press 'delete`key,and press`enter` key,it can't remove the space.
How can remove the space between the last two lines,convert its format into as below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> together.

---

<kbd>Enter</kbd> starts a new **paragraph**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> starts a **new line** without starting a new paragraph.

---

Another, more systematic, approach is to define a new style for your code-block, apply that style to only the text in question and amend the style definition to set paragraph spacing to zero for that style only.

If you are using LibreOffice to edit program source and not as part of a more complex report document, you are probably using the wrong tool.